# compute residuals within groups in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to compute within group residuals in anova using R. My data frame is

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = c(rep("group1", 5), rep("group2", 7)),
                 value = c(6.6,4.6,8.5,6.1,8.4,
                           10.7,10.1,10.9,10.7,15.6,13.8,15.9))
```

I want to use a simple way using `dplyr` or else to combine following two lines of code

```
M <- df %>% group_by(V1) %>% summarise(avg = mean(value))

df$res <- ifelse(test = df$V1 == "group1", yes = (df$value - M$avg[1])^2,
                                            no = (df$value - M$avg[2])^2)
```

I tried to use `do()` in `dplyr` but no success. I was wondering if there is a neat way of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to keep using the original `value` column along with `avg`, then use `mutate` rather than `summarize` so that the means are just placed in a new column next to the original values:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(V1) %>%
    mutate(avg = mean(value),
           res = (value - avg)^2)
```